# Compiling multiple executables with make

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I would like the following makefile to be capable of compiling multiple executables:

```
CXX      = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall --std=c++11
OBJS     = two_rung.o three_rung.o dumbinterp.o interp.o writeLadderMPO.o
PROG     = two_rung three_rung dumbinterp interp
SOURCES = two_rung.cc three_rung.cc dumbinterp.cc interp.cc writeLadderMPO.cc
HEADS = writeLadderMPO.h
INCLUDES = -I $(HOME)/ITensor
LIBS     = -L $(HOME)/ITensor/lib -litensor -lstdc++ -framework Accelerate

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cc $(HEADS)
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $(OBJS) $(SOURCES)
```

The executables are denoted by `PROG`. When I try to make one of these executables, for example `interp`, I get instead

```
Computer:folder username$ make interp
clang++ -I /Users/username/ITensor -c -o two_rung.o three_rung.o dumbinterp.o interp.o writeLadderMPO.o two_rung.cc three_rung.cc dumbinterp.cc interp.cc writeLadderMPO.cc
```

Which is to say, Make is just tossing all the files in when I call them as variables, which totally makes perfect sense. But I want it to behave like:

```
clang++ -I /Users/username/ITensor -c -o interp.o interp.cc
```

and then

```
clang++ -I /Users/username/ITensor -o interp interp.o -L $(HOME)/ITensor/lib -litensor -lstdc++ -framework Accelerate
```

How do I get Make to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to set up each program and its dependencies separately. Also, I assume not all programs depends on *all* object files?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you be more specific about what that entails? Thanks! Also, yes, each program only depends on its corresponding .o file.

Comment: Furthermore, your creation of object file, don't put any commands there, instead let `make` use implicit rules for that. Just add `INCLUDES` to `CXXFLAGS` and `make` should do the right thing (which you don't do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comments.

Consider the rule

```
$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

This will be expanded by `make` into

```
two_rung three_rung dumbinterp interp: two_rung.o three_rung.o dumbinterp.o interp.o writeLadderMPO.o
    clang++ -I $(HOME)/ITensor -o two_rung three_rung dumbinterp interp two_rung.o three_rung.o dumbinterp.o interp.o writeLadderMPO.o -L $(HOME)/ITensor/lib -litensor -lstdc++ -framework Accelerate
```

Not quite what you had in mind I think.

Instead you need to specify each executable target and dependencies explicitly:

```
two_rung: two_rung.o writeLadderMPO.o

three_rung: three_rung.o writeLadderMPO.o

dumbinterp: dumbinterp.o writeLadderMPO.o

interp: interp.o writeLadderMPO.o
```

With the flag variables set up correctly then `make` will link those correctly.

---

As for the compilation of the source files into object files, you have problems there too, where

```
%.o: %.cc $(HEADS)
    $(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $(OBJS) $(SOURCES)
```

will be expanded to

```
%.o: %.cc writeLadderMPO.h
    clang++ -I $(HOME)/ITensor -c -o two_rung.o three_rung.o dumbinterp.o interp.o writeLadderMPO.o two_rung.cc three_rung.cc dumbinterp.cc interp.cc writeLadderMPO.cc
```

That's not really how it work, you need to create each object file from each source file separately. Fortunately you can still use the same basic rule, but don't need to provide the command to create the object file:

```
%.o: %.cc $(HEADS)
```

That's almost it, no command needed. However then you also need to do e.g.

```
CXXFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
```

before this rule.

Comment: Thank you; this is essentially what I was doing before and my hope was that there existed a less cumbersome method where I wouldn't have to muck around in the makefile with every new program (I have many more than are I've kept in the post). I guess this is too much to ask for?

Comment: @Diffycue You're using macOS and I don't know how much its "native" `make` programs differs from the more common GNU make program. But if it have functions then there probably is a `$(foreach ...)` or similar function, which could be used to generate the executable rules. I haven't searched thoroughly, so I don't have a link to the macOS `make` documentation, but you should probably find it and read it for such functions and experiment with them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what make you have and what it supports, but if you are using GNU make, you could probably use static pattern rules and automatic variables (`$@`: target, `$^`: prerequisites, `$<`: first prerequisite). You could also use some make functions (`wildcard` and `patsubst`) to automate the discovery of sources and deduce the list of object files. Something like:

```
CXX      = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall --std=c++11
SOURCES  = $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJS     = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(SOURCES))
PROG     = two_rung three_rung dumbinterp interp
HEADS    = writeLadderMPO.h
INCLUDES = -I $(HOME)/ITensor
LIBS     = -L $(HOME)/ITensor/lib -litensor -lstdc++ -framework Accelerate

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): %: %.o writeLadderMPO.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cc $(HEADS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $@ $<
```

The `$(PROG): %: %.o...` rule is a static pattern rule. See the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) for a complete description.

Note: I removed `$(INCLUDES)` from the link recipe, it is useless. But I added `$(CXXFLAGS)` in the compile recipe because it was probably missing.